# How to handle Multiple result set in spring jpa hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a procedure which returns multiple result set. I have declared procedure call in namedquery annotation in entity class. I get two result set from procedure one is actual entity and other one is pojo. How can i handle this is spring jpa?

Comment: Add some code to illustrate your problem

Comment: @akuma8 I just want to know how to process multiple result sets.